# android, disabling the button even if user exits the app

Tags: android, sqlite

My program saves some data to SQLITE with datetime. There is a button save, which saves the value of 1 spinner along with datetime.
I will provide an example to make sure all understand:
User inputs at  20:03:24, now i want to disable the save button until the HOUR is at least 21:00. So every save can only be on every full hour. 
Now my idea is to read the hour from SQLITE and check if the last inputed hour is != current Hour then

```
    btn.setClickable(true);

else
    btn.setClickable(false);
```

This is what i have created and partially works.

```
public void CHECK(){

    sqliteDbHelper_ = new Sqlite_DBHelper(getActivity());
    sqLiteDatabase = sqliteDbHelper_.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {"hour_only","JAKOST"};
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("podatki", columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    Calendar calander = Calendar.getInstance();
    Integer currentHour = calander.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    gumb_poslji.setClickable(true);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    Integer lastInputedHour = cursor.getInt(0);
    Log.e(TAG+"zadnja vnesena URA",""+lastInputedHour);
    Log.e(TAG+"trenutna URA",""+currentHour);
    if (lastInputedHour == currentHour){
        gumb_poslji.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.TextMainColor));
        gumb_poslji.setClickable(false);
    }
    else
        gumb_poslji.setClickable(true);
        gumb_poslji.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));



}
```

How to implement a listener on the app that will constantly looking if there is a difference in the app?
Also be aware the button must also change state from clicable to not clicable even if a user is in the app and the hour changes.

Since i am new to java and Android i am looking for an idea or an example how to do this, not a solution. Am i thinking in a right direction?

Comment: In the onResume method, check and set there

Comment: Either use; i.) `AlarmManager` to wake/inform you app when the deadline is beat. (Not the best option) or...

Comment: ii.) Every time the app is started, check if deadline is beaten from SQLite and then setClickable. Else start a `CountDownTimer` with the difference between `currentHour` and `lastInputedHour`... Then setup button after complete...or repeat this cycle is app is killed before that

Comment: ok i managed that part, how about if user reamains in the app for 1h on the same screen? Where can i implement a method to check that constantly?

Comment: @Jan  U can also use broadcast receiver to listen `Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK` and `CHECK()`